# Determining If Set is Ring or Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Decide whether the following subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is not a ring, or is a ring but not a field, or is a field:

S = {${a + b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4} | a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q} } $ }

I tried approaching by considering the polynomial $f(x) = x^3 - 2$ $\in \mathbb{Q}[x] $ and observing that a root is $x = \sqrt[3]{2}$. Then, if there exists a set containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt[3]{2}$, we prove that S is a field as S = $ \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$. However, I have been unsuccessful. Are there any hints for tackling this?

Comment: *is a ring, field, or neither* --- Since fields are also rings, a clearer wording is: "is not a ring, or is a ring but not a field, or is a field".

Comment: Yes, I corrected it. Do you have any tips on approaching this?

Comment: The set is a field. Everything except the existence of inverses is straightforward, and to show inverses exist, one method that doesn't involve anything beyond school level algebra is to use a less trivial "rationalize the denominator" technique -- see [Show $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is a field by rationalizing](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/294993/13130) (especially my answer, which relies on a famous factorization formula).

Answer (score 0):

First show that $S$ is a ring by showing that it satisfies all ring properties. 
Consider the map $\psi:\mathbb Q[x]\to S$ by sending $f(x)\to f(\sqrt[3]{2})$. It is clear that $\psi$ is surjective with kernel $(x^3-2)$. So by the first isomorphism theorem it follows that $S=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

Comment: We haven't seen that theorem yet in my course. Only theorems we can use are from Chapter 3.2 of Shifrin's "Abstract Algebra - A Geometric Approach".